# PCB via Planning

Tags: via, pcb-layers

I have 8 layers: 2 ground planes, 4 signals layers and 2 to route power. When planning the vias, I was thinking of not using through vias for my FBGA packages. Decoupling capacitors etc. placed on the bottom layer clash with the through vias. 
Instead I am planning to use multiple vias to go from top to bottom layer using at least one intermediate layer based on whether its power or signal.

Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Are you planning vias before routing o_O?

Comment: Yes. Is that not recommended? It's my first time making a board. So please advise accordingly. I'm using Allegro PCB Designer 16.5

Comment: I was always thinking of the vias as a part of the routing which are added on demand.

Comment: Yes but I have started routing and hence need the vias now. I am wondering what is the efficient way to route for FBGAs. I know the locations of vias but wondering about layers to be addressed by the via.

Comment: It depends on the technology available. You can use so-called "blind" vias, which are not "penetrating" all of the layers, or the full through vias, which are simpler to manufacture. If you can use the simpler solution, you will avoid some troubles with manufacturing and testing.

Comment: "FBGA"? As in Ball Grid Array, or a misspelling of "FPGA"?

Comment: @FiddyOhm...Fine Ball Grid Array

Comment: Never designed a PCB, first board is an 8 layer FBGA. That's pretty brave.

Comment: Pipe: Very brave, especially since the OP used the plural: "packages". Harshad, how many FBGA packages and how many balls on each? BGA PCB designs are generally the domain of very experienced PC layout designers. Is this an academic exercise or are you designing a real product?

Comment: 3 packages: 121, 256 and 484. It's an academic exercise.

Comment: I have done PCB designing before but just not so sure about handling BGA parts as they too close and many more layers than I have done in the past.

Comment: I'm flattered to be called very brave. But then what's the maximum package size or layer count that you guys have designed? Just wish to know if my summer is certain to be ruined or what's left of it.

Comment: FPGA makers publish recommended escape routing for their parts. Even if your part is not an FPGA, you might take a look at those designs (for a similar package to yorus) to get an idea what is industry best practice for that scale of part. Generally you want to minimize the number of via types (layer pairs connected) to avoid extra manufacturing steps.

Comment: Or look at the reference designs published by the manufacturer(s) of the part(s) you're using.

Comment: @Photon: I have the escape route (location and size of via) for each of the package in sync with my design. I wish to know if my logic regarding the layering of the via is sensible or not?

Comment: If you're considering blind vias, contact your PCB fabrication vendor first. You need to determine what they can support; blind vias may be smaller laser-drilled holes that can only penetrate outer layers. If your design exceeds their manufacturing limits then it will be wasted effort, so make sure you understand what they are capable of fabricating.

Comment: More importantly, make sure you understand what blind via cost.  It may well be a nonstarter

Answer (score 3):

**"Is that the correct way to do it?"**

The "correct" way to do it is the way that works! "Works", in turn, can be a multi-dimensional term. Since you are doing this layout as an academic exercise some of these dimensions of "work" will probably not matter.

So, Dimension 1: Connectivity. If all you need to do as part of this exercise is make all of the electrical connections on the board correctly (i.e. according to a schematic, or net list), your via scheme will be fine.

If you were making a real-world PCB these other dimensions would likely play a critical role:

Dimension 2: Solderability. The integrity of the solder joints produced between a large ball count BGA package and its footprint is largely dependent on the thermal characteristics of the overall footprint geometry. Ball pads that are routed to inner layers will tend to loose heat to the inner layer during the vapor solder operation, resulting in a relatively cool pad, and thereby a cold solder joint for that ball. Those pads connected to a thin signal trace will tend to get hotter during the solder process and react oppositely - either getting the correct amount of heat to form a good solder joint or overheat causing the solder to bubble and create a void in the joint.

So, that recommended footprints and routing for a BGA are often based on their expected thermal performance during the soldering process. I have seen footprints which had a via per ball. The goal here was to achieve uniform heat distribution during the soldering process throughout the array, even though all of the vias were not connected to signals or power planes.

Dimension 3: Signal Integrity. The frequency of the signals in your circuit may require impedance matching and/or balancing if they are differential signals. The inclusion of vias in these so-called "high speed traces" can be quite troublesome to the goals of impedance control.

Further, the routing of the signals to avoid noise generation and noise susceptibility is also an issue in real-world PCBs that will likely never be known in an academic exercise.

Dimension 4: Voltage Distribution. Making sure every package gets the correct operating voltage(s) can be challenging. I've participated in designing high speed communication PCBs in which the ICs drew many amps of supply current. The IR and IL drops of the planes, traces, and vias all worked against this requirement at such supply current levels. This is another performance criteria that may never come to light in an academic PCB layout exercise.

Dimension 5: Thermal Performance. Aside from the thermal issues associated with solderability there are  those associated with actual operation. Here you are concerned with getting die-generated heat away from the IC packages. The inner planes play a large role in this by conducting heat away from the ball pads. Where you have multiple ICs, you will want to space them far enough apart that the heat from one doesn't contribute to the overheating of a neighbor.

In summary, if your academic PCB layout will only be judged on connectivity, your summer should be relatively enjoyable. However, don't expect a "vacation" when you get to laying out such a complex PCB in the Real World of Electrical Engineering.

Comment: So, I'm sticking to dimension 1 for now and going ahead. I can revisit the rest of the dimensions when I proceed with more understanding. I like the answer more cause you also used my "summer vacation" part.